# Kinect one profundidade

Tags: kinect

Como analisar uma imagem feita com o Kinect One, sendo a profundidade feita com o infra vermelho. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Você não precisa criar uma nova pergunta, você pode editar a que você já fez e colocar mais informações.

Comment: Não precisa criar outra pergunta, edite a [anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68534/91) de mais detalhes

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português @carlos . Ao fazer perguntas no SOpt você deve explicar detalhadamente o seu problema da melhor maneira possível e incluir o código relevante que está a gerar este problema para ajudar os outros membros da comunidade a recriar este problema. Você pode também visitar a página [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)